# Nested if statements vs extra else if?

Tags: if-statement, logic, language-agnostic

I come across a lot of logic work where I'm not sure what design pattern is better for if statements. In these situations, I can usually put in a nested if statement, or alternatively. These two cases are shown below. What are the pros and cons of both, is there a standard I should follow?

```
if (val > 0 && is_on)
{
  // (1)
}
else if (val > 0)
{
  // (2)
} 
else
{
  // (3)
}
```

```
if (val > 0)
{
  if(is_on)
  {
    // same as (1)
  }
  else
  {
    // same as (2)
  }
}
else
{
  // same as (3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are absolutely right in that your primary focus should be be readability, I want to address another difference: execution performance.

In the first example, there are 2 conditions that need evaluated before the `else` branch can run. If as we scale the number of conditions baked into this else/if ladder, the amount of evaluation to get to the `else` branch grows linearly. Now, we aren't expecting to have ten thousand conditions or anything, but it is something to take note of nonetheless.

Now, in your second example, we check the common condition between the first two branches, and if that fails, we quick-fail to the `else` branch, with no extra tests. In the extreme case, this can somewhat resemble a binary search for the correct code block- branching left and right until it finds its match, as opposed to a linear scan that checks each in order one-by-one.

Now, does this mean you should use the latter? Not necessarily- readability is more important, and if you're writing in a compiled language, the compiler will likely optimize away all that away anyways. And even if you're in an interpreted language, the performance hit is probably going to be negligible compared to everything else anyways, unless this is the hot section of a hot loop.

However, if you are bothered by the "wastefulness" of the repetition in the first example, but would rather avoid huge amounts of nesting, often languages will provide an *assignment expression* syntax, giving you a 3rd option, where you compute the result once and store it to a variable inline, for reuse in subsequent code.

For example:

```
if (expensive_func1() > 0 && is_on)
{
  // (1)
}
else if (expensive_func1() > 0 && expensive_func2() > 0)
{
  // (2)
} 
else
{
  // (3)
}
```

Becomes:

```
if ((is_alive = expensive_func1() > 0) && is_on)
{
  // (1)
}
else if (is_alive && expensive_func2() > 0)
{
  // (2)
} 
else
{
  // (3)
}
```

This saves us from recomputing the common sub expressions between our conditionals, in languages were we can't rely on a compiler to do that for us. Sure, we could just assign these to variables explicitly before the if statements, but then we bite the bullet of evaluating all shared expressions, rather than lazily evaluating them as needed (imagine we compute `expensive_func2 > 0` for reuse in a 3rd if/else, only to find out we didn't need it, that we're taking the first branch).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any specific  pros or cons to any of the approach. Its all depends upon how you want to design your code and what you think is more readable to anyone who is looking at your code for the first time.

As per me, the first approach looks better as its more **readable** and contains fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is more readable.  But as the logic expressions (e.g. "val > 0 && is_on") get longer, it starts to make more sense to merge towards the second approach.  The second one is easier to debug, so you could start there and then merge back.  I'd match the style of the surrounding code/"code-policy" ultimately.